# Both buttons are appearing when only one is supposed to

Tags: python, django

So it is supposed to show remove from cart when user has that item in their cart and add to cart when they don't, I am trying to use django template language for this but both buttons are appearing anyway, `home` function handles the page i am talking about, It passes all the variables to `home.html`.

home.html

```
<h1>Here are products</h1>
<h1>{{ error }}</h1>
<h1>Your cart currently costs ${{ price }}</h1>
{% for book in books %}
<h3>{{ book.name }}</h3>
<img src= "/media/{{ book.image }}" alt="">
<p>{{ book.description }}</p>
{% for usercart in cart %}
{% if book == usercart.book %}
<form method="POST" action="/removefromcartforhome/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="removeid" value="{{ book.id }}">remove item from cart</button>
</form>
{% else %}
<form method="POST" action="/addtocartforhome/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="bookid" value="{{ book.id }}">Add to cart</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout, authenticate
from django.db import IntegrityError
from .models import Book, CartItem, OrderItem
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import BookForm
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
import random
# Create your views here.

removederror = ''


def calculate(request):
    oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    fianlprice = 0
    for item in oof:
        fianlprice += item.book.price

        


def signupuser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'main/alreadyloggedin.html')
    elif request.user != request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render(request, 'main/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm()})
        elif request.method == "POST":
            if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
                try:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                    user.save()
                    login(request, user)
                    return render(request, 'main/UserCreated.html')
                except IntegrityError:
                    return render(request, 'main/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'That username has already been taken. Please choose a new username'})
            else:
                return render(request, 'main/signupuser.html', {'form':UserCreationForm(), 'error':'Passwords did not match'})

def signinuser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'main/alreadyloggedin.html', {'error':'You are already logged in'})
    elif request.user != request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "GET":
            return render(request, 'main/signinuser.html', {'form':AuthenticationForm()})
        elif request.method == "POST":
            user = authenticate(request, username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
            if user is None:
                return render(request, 'main/signinuser.html', {'form':AuthenticationForm(), 'error':'Username and password did not match'})
            else:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request, 'main/loggedin.html', {'error':'You are now logged in!'})
 
def logoutuser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "GET": 
            return render(request, 'main/logoutuser.html')
        elif request.method == "POST":
            logout(request)
            return render(request, 'main/loggedin.html', {'error':'You are now logged out!'})
    elif request.user != request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'main/alreadyloggedin.html', {'error':'You are not logged in'})
    

def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        fianlprice = 0
        for item in oof:
            fianlprice += item.book.price
        books = Book.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'books':books, 'price':fianlprice, 'error':'', 'cart':oof})
    else:
        books = Book.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'books':books})


@login_required
def addtocartforhome(request):
    oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    fianlprice = 0
    for item in oof:
        fianlprice += item.book.price
    books = Book.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user, book=Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['bookid'])).exists():
            return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'books':books, 'error':'That book is already in your cart!', 'price':fianlprice})
            
        else:
            try:
                book = Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['bookid'])
            except Book.DoesNotExist:
                return redirect('home')
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(book=book, user=request.user)
            return redirect('home')
            
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'main/signinuser.html', {'form':BookForm})
                                            

@login_required
def addtocartforproducts(request):
    oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    fianlprice = 0
    for item in oof:
        fianlprice += item.book.price
    books = Book.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user, book=Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['bookid'])).exists():
            return render(request, 'main/products.html', {'books':books, 'error':'That book is already in your cart!', 'price':fianlprice})
            
        else:
            try:
                book = Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['bookid'])
            except Book.DoesNotExist:
                return redirect('showproducts')
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(book=book, user=request.user)
            return redirect('showproducts')
            
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'main/signinuser.html', {'form':BookForm})

@login_required
def removefromcartforcart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        fianlprice = 0
        for item in oof:
            fianlprice += item.book.price
        books = Book.objects.all()
        removebook = Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['removeid'])
        try:
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(book=removebook, user=request.user).delete()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return render(request, 'main/cart.html', {'books':books, 'error':'That item is not in your cart!', 'price':fianlprice})
        return redirect('showcart')
    else:
        pass

@login_required
def removefromcartforhome(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        fianlprice = 0
        for item in oof:
            fianlprice += item.book.price
        books = Book.objects.all()
        removebook = Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['removeid'])
        try:
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(book=removebook, user=request.user).delete()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            removederror = 'That item is not in your cart!'
            return redirect('home')
        return redirect('home')
    else:
        pass

@login_required
def removefromcartforproducts(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        fianlprice = 0
        for item in oof:
            fianlprice += item.book.price
        books = Book.objects.all()
        removebook = Book.objects.get(pk=request.POST['removeid'])
        try:
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(book=removebook, user=request.user).delete()
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return render(request, 'main/products.html', {'books':books, 'error':'That item is not in your cart!', 'price':fianlprice})
        return redirect('showproducts')
    else:
        pass


def showproducts(request):
    oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    fianlprice = 0
    for item in oof:
        fianlprice += item.book.price
    books = Book.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'main/products.html', {'books':books, 'price':fianlprice})


@login_required
def showcart(request):
    oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    fianlprice = 0
    for item in oof:
        fianlprice += item.book.price
    oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'main/cart.html', {'cart':oof, 'price':fianlprice})

@login_required
def makeorder(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request_cart = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        if not CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
            return render(request, 'main/orderdone.html', {'error':'Your cart is empty'})
        else:
            for item in request_cart:
                if OrderItem.objects.filter(user=item.user, book=item.book):
                    return render(request, 'main/orderdone.html', {'error':'You already own this book!'})
                else:
                    for item in request_cart:
                        createorder(item.book, item.user)
                    request_cart.delete()
                    return render(request, 'main/orderdone.html', {'error':'Your order has been placed!'})
    else:
        return redirect('home')


def createorder(product, user):
    order_item = Book.objects.get(pk=product.id)
    order_user = User.objects.get(username=user.username)
    unique_id = ''
    for x in range(10):
        letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
        numbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
        choice =  random.randint(1,5)
        if choice == 1:
            unique_id += letters[random.randint(0,25)]
        elif choice == 2:
            unique_id += numbers[random.randint(0,9)]
        elif choice == 3:
            unique_id += letters[random.randint(0,25)]
        elif choice == 4:
            unique_id += numbers[random.randint(0,9)]
        elif choice == 5:
            unique_id += letters[random.randint(0,25)]
    OrderItem.objects.create(user=order_user, book=order_item, order_id=unique_id)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class CartItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1):

It's showing the both buttons because of your second "for" (If "cart" length >=2).

In just one of the iterations of the second "for", the "book" of the first "for" will fall into "remove from cart". In the remaining, it will fall into the "add from cart", since it will be only once in the "cart" variable.

If you are only comparing books, you can return them at you variable "cart". So this way, you won't need the second for.

Like this:

views.py

```
def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        oof = CartItem.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('book', flat=True)
    .
    .
    .
```

*Note that now, your variable "cart", is a list of books. So you may rename the variable*

home.html

```
{% for book in books %}
<h3>{{ book.name }}</h3>
<img src= "/media/{{ book.image }}" alt="">
<p>{{ book.description }}</p>
    {% if book in cart %}
        <form method="POST" action="/removefromcartforhome/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" name="removeid" value="{{ book.id }}">remove item from cart</button>
        </form>
        {% else %}
        <form method="POST" action="/addtocartforhome/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" name="bookid" value="{{ book.id }}">Add to cart</button>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is considering using your structure, and not changing it.

Comment: This does not work too, Remove item from cart does not show up

Comment: Make sure you have that book "selected" in a CartItem model. both buttons still appears ?

Comment: Add to cart appears but not remove from cart

Comment: If it is working correctly then, the objects in your variable "books", aren't in the variable "cart".